# com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: Error parsing P:\...\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: Error parsing P:\CodSoft\codsoft_alarm_clock\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<application android:label="codsoft_alarm_clock"
    android:name="${applicationName}"      
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" 
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
        android:exported="true">
        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService" 
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Solution Of this code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.